# MS Access Query Sum if column text matches

Tags: ms-access

I have a query that I want to summarize expenses by location in MS Access. So far I have it so that it will give me some of it by an expression(event.amt*event.costper) . What I want want is when is to sum the expression by location.

Comment: Such if text in the category.location matches it will then sum up that location. I know it's doable but google isn't friendly to the question.

Comment: You'll get much more useful responses if you include the related data structure(s) and ideally show some example source data + desired result.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/8qLwa I want the a sum by location from subtotal2.

So if location name matches such as "4141 Portland" it will give me a sum for subtotal 2. Does that help?

Comment: Instead of manualy going through and adding auto sum
      A       |         B          |   C
   1  Site1 (costper*amt)
   2  Site1 (costper*amt)
   3 Site1  (costper*amt) =sum(b1+b3)

Comment: Dont think I'm following you. Sounds like a simple _group by_, but since you're using that already I expect I'm missing something. Have a look at this and see if you can come up with a simple example that demonstates the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve (editing your question is a better idea than commenting).

Comment: Full codehttps://pastebin.com/pcZuC7mt

Answer (score 0):

First of all the screenshot of the query and the SQL statement posted on pastebin does not match. Therefore I choose the SQL-statement für my answer.

You could drop the "group by" for "dbo_Clients.Name, dbo_Categories.Name, 
dbo_Phases.Description", then you would have the summary für each location.

or

if it is necessary to group by for "dbo_Clients.Name, dbo_Categories.Name, 
dbo_Phases.Description" to do the right calculation of subtotal1,  You need to do a second query baesd on yours, just doing the "group by" for dbo_Locations.Name and sum up subTotal1